# Why my while loop in c++ wont run correctly?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am just a newbie to programming and I was trying to write a while loop that runs as long as the input (`num`) is not a integer which doesn't ends with zero. What happen is when I enter a number that ends with zero, the program runs the loop correctly, but when i enter something nonsense such as `rofl` the program only print `The input is not valid.` and won't repeat the loop. I have tried to look for solutions but I am still stuck after a hour. Anyone can help me here? Thx so much!

```
void rev_sum() {
    int num;
    int a = 1;
    while (a < 2) {
        cout << "Please input a natural number without zero at the end:\n";
        cin >> num;
        if (!cin) {
            cout << "The input is not valid.\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
        }
        if (num % 10 == 0) {
            cout << "The number cannot have zero at the end\n";
        } else {
            cout << "gj\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer from below (if anything solved your issue from below) so that people facing the same issue can quickly find it.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing

```
cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```

With

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

And change the

```
if (num % 10 == 0)
```

To

```
else if (num % 10 == 0)
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
void rev_sum() {
    int num;
    int a = 1;
    while (a < 2) {
        cout << "Please input a natural number without zero at the end:\n";
        cin >> num;
        if (!cin) {
            cout << "The input is not valid.\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else if (num % 10 == 0) {
            cout << "The number cannot have zero at the end\n";
        } else {
            cout << "gj\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!thank you<3 Also thank everyone who have helped~

Answer (score 1):

```
if (num % 10 == 0) {
```

could be

```
else if (num % 10 == 0) {
```

otherwise the other else case might get executed

Answer (score 1):

You set `a = 1` at the start of the loop and then never change `a` which means the only way to leave your while loop is if you hit the break statement.  If your loop is not looping then it must be stuck somewhere. I'm unfamiliar with the statements `if (!cin)` and `cin.ignore(...)` so those are top suspects to check (or change). The statement `cin >> num;` completes no matter what they type so you can check to see what 'num' is equal to when you enter "rofl". Then after it fails, you still use `num` so you are processing this unintentional entry.  You can add `continue;` after `cin.ignore(...)` to jump back to the top of the while loop and ask the question again. You can also print something after the while loop in order to know when you get out.

With all that said, I would never trust the user to enter acceptable information and I would never trust cin to process it for me.  Personally, I would read cin as a string using cin.getline(buffer, buffer_size); And then I would complain to the user if they filled the buffer or gave me something that was not an integer (which you can check with a function like [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)). Then you can spit back exactly what they gave you and you can be specific about your complaint.

Answer (score 0):

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max())
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it not make more sense to only check that the number ends in 0 if the input was valid....

```
void rev_sum() {
    int num;
    int a = 1;
    while (a < 2) {
        cout << "Please input a natural number without zero at the end:\n";
        cin >> num;
        if (!cin) {
            cout << "The input is not valid.\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
        } else {
            if (num % 10 == 0) {
                cout << "The number cannot have zero at the end\n";
            } else {
                cout << "gj\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```